# Why are hash values inconsistent between different program executions?

Tags: c++, hash

As part of a research project, I was testing some hash functions that I found on Eternally Confuzzled [here](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx).  The project has to do with page caching algorithms and the hash behavior itself never seemed important until now, but this is still more for my own curiosity.  To test, I'm using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned oat_hash(void *key, int len);

int main()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hash: " << oat_hash(&name, sizeof(string)) << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name again: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hash: " << oat_hash(&name, sizeof(string)) << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

unsigned oat_hash(void *key, int len)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) key;
    unsigned h = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h += p[i];
        h += (h << 10);
        h ^= (h >> 6);
    }

    h += (h << 3);
    h ^= (h >> 11);
    h += (h << 15);

    return h;
}
```

Program execution 1 output:

```
Enter a name: John Doe
Hash: 4120494494

Enter the name again: John Doe
Hash: 4120494494
```

Program execution 2 output:

```
Enter a name: John Doe
Hash: 3085275063

Enter the name again: John Doe
Hash: 3085275063
```

I entered the same string and got the same hash value during the same program execution, but why would the values be different for different program executions?  Wouldn't different hash values indicate different data?

Comment: I just did 5 runs and got the exact same output.

Comment: You probably entered a space and didn't realize it.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I checked for that.  I even used different input and the result (that of getting different hash values for different program execution) was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementations of `std::string` contain a pointer. You are hashing the internals of the `std::string` and not the actual text of the `std::string`. On modern systems, the stack location is randomized and also the freestore allocations are randomized, resulting into different internals of `std::string` each time you run it.

You probably might want to change the code like this:

```
unsigned oat_hash(void const *key, int len)
{
    unsigned char const *p = static_cast<unsigned char const *>(key);
    // etc.
}

//...

cout << "Hash: " << oat_hash(name.c_str(), name.size()) << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this is a good explanation and solution.  If I could upvote, I certainly would.

Comment: Really interesting to know.  +1